# UWP. Page.BottomAppBar does not change when page is hidden

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml, win-universal-app

I have a simple UWP application with pivot Control. This pivot Control has three buttons and each button should load a new page. It's working.

```
...
<PivotItem>
    <PivotItem.Header>
        <local:TabHeader Label="Page1" />
    </PivotItem.Header>
    <local:Page1 x:Name="TapOnPage1" />
</PivotItem>
<PivotItem>
    <PivotItem.Header>
        <local:TabHeader Label="Page2" />
    </PivotItem.Header>
    <local:Page2 x:Name="TapOnPage2" />
</PivotItem>
<PivotItem>
    <PivotItem.Header>
        <local:TabHeader Label="Page3" />
    </PivotItem.Header>
    <local:Page3 x:Name="TapOnPage3" />
</PivotItem>
...
```

Each page is something like this:

```
<Page
x:Class="MyApp.Page1"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:MyApp"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d">

   <Page.BottomAppBar>
       <CommandBar x:Name="PageLiveVideoCommandBar" >
           <AppBarButton Label="Rewind" Icon="Previous" x:Name="RewindAppBarBtn" />
           <AppBarButton Label="Play" Icon="Play" x:Name="PlayAppBarBtn"/>
           <AppBarButton Label="Forward" Icon="Next" x:Name="NextAppBarBtn"/>
       </CommandBar>
   </Page.BottomAppBar>

   <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}" />
</Page>
```

Page1.xaml has 3 AppBarButtons, the second page has 4 buttons and the last one page has 3 buttons. If I change from page1 to page2 ( using pivot buttons ), the BottomAppBar changes correctly but if I try to show page1 again, this page is shown but BottomAppBar does not change. BottomAppBar of second page is already loaded and I don't know why.

I've tried to change the appBarButton visibility in Pivot Selection changed event but it does not work.

Comment: can you show us .cs file and app.xaml,app.xaml.cs?

Comment: `if I try to show page1 again` what does it mean ? It mean you navigate the current frame to page1 directly or you go back to the page which has the Pivot and navigate to page 1 from there ?

Comment: It means I navigate from the current frame to page1. The MainPage has a pivot control with three buttons. Each button loads a new page with his own BottomAppBar. If I change from Page1 to Page2 or from Page1 to Page3 ( using pivot buttons ), it works fine, each page loads his own BottomAppBar but if I click on page1 again, his BottomAppBar does not show.

Comment: So Is this the sequence? Mainpage->page1-> go back to mainpage->page2->gobackto mainpage->page1?